# Make react js mobile mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This has been bugging for days but how do you scale a react js to make it have a mobile friendly. In other web frameworks like Django and others that work with plain css and javascript , meta tag usually does the trick for me, but i have no idea how to scale  my now completed react js site

Comment: You could use something simple as vanilla css or a bit more advance with something like styled-components. Both cases using media queries.

Comment: you can still use plain css and meta tags in the index.html file

Comment: i have finished the project using jsx and css already so i cant use .html files